# Is there a specific terminology for these upper unitriangular matrices?

Tags: matrices, notation, terminology

I came across upper unitriangular $n \times n$ matrices of the following form (here for $n = 5$):
$$
\pmatrix{
1 & a & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 \\
0 & 1 & a   & a^2 & a^3 \\
0 & 0 & 1   & a   & a^2 \\
0 & 0 & 0   & 1   & a   \\ 
0 & 0 & 0   & 0   & 1  }
$$
Given their very simple shape, I wondered if they had a specific name. Even without a name, references would be welcome.

Comment: $(I-aN)^{-1}$ where $N$ is the nilpotent matrix with just the $n_{i,i+1} = 1$  and all else zero